# Firefox Extension/Addon : Reading a text file from remote server(URL)

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, mozilla

After wasting my two days to find out what's going wrong with this script, finally I decide to ask it.

**What I am trying to do**

I am trying to read a text file from remote server. Then storing all text file updates to an SQLITE database at the time of my Firefox Extension/Addon get loaded.

**What I tried**

```
var updatereader = {

    start: function () {
    //alert('reading update');
        var fURL = null;
        var ioService = null;
        var fURI = null;
        var httpChannel = null;

        fURL = "http://www.example.com/addon/mlist.txt";
        ioService = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/io-service;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIIOService);
        fURI = ioService.newURI(fURL, null, null);
        httpChannel = ioService.newChannelFromURI(fURI).QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIHttpChannel);
        httpChannel.asyncOpen(updatereader.StreamReader, null);
    },

    onUpdateCompleted: function () {

    },

    StreamReader:
    {
        fOutputStream: null,
        fPointer: null,
        tempFile: "mlist.txt",

        onStartRequest: function (aRequest, aContext) {
        //alert('onStart');
            updatereader.StreamReader.fOutputStream = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/file-output-stream;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIFileOutputStream);
            updatereader.StreamReader.fPointer = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/directory_service;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIProperties).get("ProfD", Components.interfaces.nsIFile);
            updatereader.StreamReader.fPointer.append(updatereader.StreamReader.tempFile);
            updatereader.StreamReader.fOutputStream.init(updatereader.StreamReader.fPointer, 0x02 | 0x20 | 0x08, 0644, 0);
        },

        onDataAvailable: function (aRequest, aContext, aInputStream, aOffset, aCount) {
        //control flow is not entering here - may be here is somehting missing
            var sStream = null;
            var tempBuffer = null;
            sStream = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/scriptableinputstream;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIScriptableInputStream);
            sStream.init(aInputStream);
            tempBuffer = sStream.read(aCount);
            updatereader.StreamReader.fOutputStream.write(tempBuffer, aCount);
        },

        onStopRequest: function (aRequest, aContext, aStatusCode) {
        //alert('onStop');
            var currentDate = new Date();
            if (aStatusCode == 0) {
                fileInputStream = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/file-input-stream;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIFileInputStream);

                updatereader.StreamReader.fOutputStream.close();
                fileInputStream.init(updatereader.StreamReader.fPointer, 0x01, 0, 0);
                lineInputStream = fileInputStream.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsILineInputStream);

             //pass data to somewhere 
              var dbH = new dbstore();
              dbH.updateData(lineInputStream);

                lineInputStream.close();

                updatereader.StreamReader.fPointer.remove(false);


                updatereader.onUpdateCompleted();
            } else {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Problem:**

Getting nothing in `lineInputStream` which passes the read data to somewhere else for storing it.

**Area of problem:**

Program control flow is not entring to this section

```
 onDataAvailable:
```

Not getting any error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there doesn't really seem to be any need to read the file to the disk first (unless it is really, really big).

I'd just use `XMLHttpRequest` to get the file, which when run from a privileged context (e.g. add-on code, but not a website) can access any and every valid URI.
`XMLHttpRequest` will simplify almost everything, e.g. no more onDataAvailable, (usually) no more manual text converting, etc.
Also, no need to ever hit the disk during the transfer.

Code would look something like this:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET", "http://www.example.com/addon/mlist.txt"); // file:/// would work too, BTW
req.overrideMimeType("text/plain");
req.addEventListener("load", function() {
  // Do something with req.responseText
}, false);
req.addEventListener("error", function() {
  // Handle error
}, false);
req.send();
```

If you want to use `XMLHttpRequest` in a non-window, e.g. js code module or js components, then you need to first initialize a constructor. This is not required for windows, including XUL windows and by that XUL overlays.

```
// Add XMLHttpRequest constructor, if not already present
if (!('XMLHttpRequest' in this)) {
    this.XMLHttpRequest = Components.Constructor("@mozilla.org/xmlextras/xmlhttprequest;1", "nsIXMLHttpRequest");
}
```

SDK users should use the [`request`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/request.html) module, or [`net/xhr`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/net/xhr.html) if a lower-level API is required.

PS: If you're still interested in using *raw* channels, here is a minimal example I coded up in a Scratchpad (to run, open a Scratchpad for a privileged location, e.g. `about:newtab`).
You shouldn't alert from your own implementation: `alert()` will spin the event loop and causes reentrant code, which is  not supported in this context.

```
var {
    classes: Cc,
    interfaces: Ci,
    results: Cr,
    utils: Cu
} = Components;

Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/XPCOMUtils.jsm")
Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");

var ConverterStream = Components.Constructor(
    "@mozilla.org/intl/converter-input-stream;1",
    "nsIConverterInputStream",
    "init");
var RC = Ci.nsIConverterInputStream.DEFAULT_REPLACEMENT_CHARACTER;

function Listener() {
    this.content = "";
}
Listener.prototype = {
    QueryInterface: XPCOMUtils.generateQI([Ci.nsIStreamListener]),
    onStartRequest: function(req, ctx) {
        console.log("start");
    },
    onDataAvailable: function(req, ctx, stream, offset, count) {
        console.log("data", count);
        try {
            var cs = new ConverterStream(stream, null /* utf-8 */, 4096, RC);
            try {
                var str = {};
                while (cs.readString(4096, str)) {
                    this.content += str.value;
                }
            }
            finally {
                cs.close();
            }
        }
        catch (ex) {
            console.error("data", ex.message, ex);
        }
    },
    onStopRequest: function(req, ctx, status) {
        console.log("stop", status,
                    this.content.substr(0, 20), this.content.length);
    }
};

var uri = Services.io.newURI("http://example.org", null, null);
Services.io.newChannelFromURI(uri).asyncOpen(new Listener(), null);
```

Comment: @namier Thanks for replay, I am very much new,  `req.responseText` returning nothing. What is use of `req.send();` I want to follow your first part of code. So could you please make it more understandable. Something like a function that just return text when we pass an URL

Comment: There are tons of resources on the web discussing the use XMLHttpRequest. It is one of the most important building blocks of the modern web, after all. Here is a start: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest